# Is there a way to focus a popover for a Safari extension?

Tags: safari, focus, popover

Just wanted to know if anyone knew how to put the focus on a popover for a Safari extension. Currently, the popover acts as if the window is inactive. This prevents any mouseover events from working and trying to type in any input field is difficult because there is no flashing cursor.

Answer (score 0):

According to a post on the Safari developer forums, this is a known issue with Lion and they are looking into it.